# Not able to deploy via VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops

While deploying through VSTS I am getting the error as below. This works for some deployment but some are failed and that is weird. I checked the powershell version as well on the server with which the deployment is happening, but no luck.

Is there any setting which needs to be modified to get it working?

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'website'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.Site" value of type "Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.Site" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.Site".

Comment: What did you deploy from VSTS to Azure, is it a website project? And can you show the whole build log by setting system.debug as true?

Comment: Hi Team , i deployed a content on Azure Website using VSTS. Now I found the solution for this . Its the 6.x.x version of AzureRM that has a problem , i uninstalled it and installed the 5.x.x version of it and the issue got resolved. So this issue can be closed now.

Answer (score 1):

I deployed a content on Azure Website using VSTS. However, the 6.x.x version of AzureRM that has a problem, I uninstalled it and installed the 5.x.x version of it and the issue got resolved.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here. If possible, you could mark it as the answer. So it could help other community members to find the answer easily and conveniently.